# Why does concatenation of strings with escaped characters work differently in this Perl example?

Tags: perl, escaping

there: 
I'm new to Perl, and get a string concatenation problem of it. I have two strings below:

```
my $string1 = "hello\U\Q \t\n\f\b\aWorld" . "\n" . "\E";
my $string2 = "hello\U\Q \t\n\f\b\aWorld\n\E";
```

They are looked the same to me, until i print them out. 
`$string1` looks like this:

```
hello\ \    \
\
 \WORLD
```

and with a bell ring.

`$string2` is this one:

```
hello\ \    \
\
 \WORLD\
```

with the same bell ring, and a backslash at the tail.

Why does `$string2` get a backslash at its end but `$string1` doesn't?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use `\Q` you're telling it to quote (put a backslash in front of) all the characters that aren't matched by `\w`.  The result is that you're getting a backslash added every time there's a backslash in your code.  e.g. `\a` creates the bell sound but your string gets a backslash added in.  When you use `\Q` it behaves this way until you reach `\E` **or** get to the end of the string.

When you create `$string1` you actually have 3 separate strings that you're adding together so they're  evaluated separately.  The result is that only the first of the 3 is affected by the `\Q`.

In the second example the `\n\E` results in `\\` in the string.  When you print this out it results in the trailing backslash you're seeing.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: your answer is really helpful. thank you for that. BTW, `\a` creates the bell sound actually:)

Comment: Hehe... of course it does.  I actually *know* what \b is and still got it wrong!  Edited to not confuse anyone that reads this later.

Answer (score 7):

Because `\Q` quotes any metacharacters (including `"\"`) till `\E` or the end of the string. If you want them to print the same, use:

```
my $s1 = "hello\U\Q \t\n\f\b\aWorld" . "\Q\n" . "\E";
```

To check:

```
my $s2 = "hello\U\Q \t\n\f\b\aWorld\n\E";
$s1 eq $s2 && print '$s1 is equal to $s2', "\n";
```